# Advanced custom fields - If/ while field problem

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

The way I am trying to set this up is that if a link has not been chosen then only the image will be displayed, but if a link is chosen as well as an image then I want the link to be wrapped around the image, here is an example of what I have at the moment:

```
<?php if(get_field('block_repeater')): ?>
     <ul>

         <?php while(has_sub_field('block_repeater')): ?>
         <li>
            <!-- problem -->
             <?php if( get_sub_field('block_link') ): ?>

                 <?php while(has_sub_field('block_image')): ?>
                    <a class="img" href="<?php the_sub_field('block_link'); ?>">
                         <img src="<?php the_sub_field('block_image'); ?>" alt="" />
                         <span class="square-arrow"></span>
                     </a>
                 <?php endwhile; ?>

             <?php endif; ?>
            <!--//problem -->

             <?php if( get_sub_field('block_image') ): ?>
                 <img src="<?php the_sub_field('block_image'); ?>" alt="" />
             <?php endif; ?>
         </li>
         <?php endwhile; ?>

     </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The does not seem to be working correctly though as its rendering out about a hundred of these:

```
<a class="img" href="">
<img alt="" src="">
<span class="square-arrow"></span>
</a>
```

Don't suppose anyone knows what I have done wrong please?

Comment: why you are using while loop?

Comment: I am trying to check if block_link exists and then block_image, is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if` instead of `while` because you want to compare if a field is exist or has some value, by using `while` you are looping trough and this loop can't stop until your php's execution time limit is ended, try this.

```
<?php if (get_field('block_repeater')) { ?>
<ul>
    <?php if (has_sub_field('block_repeater')) : ?>
        <li>
            <!-- problem -->
            <?php $block_link = get_sub_field('block_link');
            $block_image = get_sub_field('block_image');

            if ($block_image) { ?>
                <?php if ($block_link) { ?><a class="img" href="<?php the_sub_field('block_link'); ?>"><?php } ?>
                    <img src="<?php the_sub_field('block_image'); ?>" alt="" />
                    <span class="square-arrow"></span>
                <?php if ($block_link) { ?></a><?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```